# Shard of Greed - Clarification about counters and usage

Tags: yu-gi-oh

There is a spell card called [Shard of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shard_of_Greed) which has the following effect:

> Each time you draw a card(s) for your normal draw in your Draw Phase, place 1 Greed Counter on this card. You can send this card with 2 or more Greed Counters to the Graveyard; draw 2 cards.

After reading the effect of this card, I have planned to make the following steps during a duel *(in my turn)*:

- Summon [Card Guard](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Guard) in attack mode to activate its effect: *place **1** Guard Counter*.
- Place another card *or use a copy of [Card Guard](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Guard)* already placed in my field *which adds one more counter*.
- Activate [Shard of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shard_of_Greed) on my side of the field.
- Give [Shard of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shard_of_Greed) those counters and send `Shard of Greed` to the Graveyard and in my next turn<sup>1</sup> draw **3** cards.

Basically, I'm trying to emulate the effect of the spell card called **[Pot Of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Pot_of_Greed)**.

I'm wondering if the steps mentioned here in my question are valid. I already checked the [rulings of this card](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Shard_of_Greed), but the page doesn't mention certain things related to my question. I also sent some tweets to users who have more knowledge about Yu-Gi-Oh!, but I haven't received answers so far.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not sure if the effect of [Shard of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shard_of_Greed) is activated immediately after sending this card to the Graveyard or if I have to wait for my next turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does not work for two reasons. The first reason is that [Shard of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shard_of_Greed) can only use greed counters. This does not necessarily mean that you can only use counters from its own effect, but at the moment there are no other card that exist in the game that use **greed counters**.

The second reason is that the card explicitly says:

> You can send this card with 2 or more Greed Counters to the Graveyard; draw 2 cards.

Because it does not say that you get to draw one card for every counter on it, you would not be allowed to draw more than *two* cards.

Also [Shard of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shard_of_Greed)'s activate effect has a spell speed of one, which means that you can only activate it either during your **Main Phase 1** or during your **Main Phase 2**. I hope this helps to clarify the card for you.

Additional information regarding the commented questions:

Cards like [Skelengel](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Skelengel) and other cards that allow you to draw will not let you more greed counters on this card. The reason being that the card specifies:

> Each time you draw a card(s) for your normal draw in your Draw Phase

Meaning that you can not add more counters on to [Shard of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shard_of_Greed) with the effects of cards, only by normally drawing a card. Also the part that says "card(s)" makes it so that even if you had a card that allowed you to draw more cards during your draw phase (ie: [Heart of the Underdog](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_of_the_Underdog)) you will not be able to place multiple counters on your card during the same turn.

Also your question on counters is relatively simple. There are various types of counters in the game. Spellcasters typically use **Spell Counters**, and **Six Samurai** usually use **Bushido Counters** the reason for differing between these counters is that the card makers don't want people being able to abuse cards such as [Shard of Greed](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shard_of_Greed) in the exact kind of situation you are describing. This also means that when playing, you need a way to differentiate between the types of counters you have on the field if you are using multiple counters.

Comment: If during **Main Phase 1** or **Main Phase 2** I use other card(s) to draw cards (example: flip summon `Skelengen`), that would add `Greed Counters` to `Shard of Greed`? Also, I want share the [comment](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/30307/shard-of-greed-clarification-about-counters-and-usage/31357#comment42425_31339) about counters that I made in other answer provided by other user.

Comment: @Mauricio I have addressed your questions within my edited answer. Please let me know if you have any more.

Answer (score 1):

Shard of Greed specifically needs "Greed Counters" so even if you did use the "guard counters" off Card Guard the effect of Shard of Greed wouldn't be useable as they are incorrect counters.

You would need to wait until shard of greed had built up the counters from it's own effect before you could use it.

Answer (score 0):

If "Shard of Greed" has two Greed Counters on it, then you can activate its effect only during your turn's Main Phase. This starts a Chain Link.
Basically when it has two counter send to graveyard and draw two cards